# Random Forests interpretability

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have been using the sklearn `RandomForestClassifier` to solve a binary classification problem.

For a particular sample prediction, I would like to be able **to know how to change the features' values to make the prediction change**.

E.g. let's say I have an entry with `[size = 15, width = 8, height = 13]` and the model gives me a`probability = 0.9` to be of `class 1`. What I would like to be able to say is "change `size` from `15` to `10`" and then your `probability=0.1` for example.

Then optimally, what I would like is the smallest "gradient" in the features values to move from one class to another (or the one that gives the most change in probability).

Maybe I'm wrong but from what I've read the packages LIME and TreeInterpreter do not provide this kind of information?

Comment: In this particular case, all your features are numeric (and moreover, integer). Sometimes, features are categorical.

Answer (score 1):

Partial dependence plots approximate the dependence between the target and a particular independent variable marginalised on all other independent variables.

While it doesn't give exact gradient at all points.  It helps us get an intuition of the variable behavior.

You can find more about it here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.plot_partial_dependence.html

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to interpreter a Random Forest:

- If you use sklearn Random Forest you can use `feature_importances_` class attribute (higher is better)
- A more general way to interpreter a "black box model" is [sensitivity analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis) and i think in your question you guess this

Comment: do you have any specific doc or packages about that sensitivity analysis?

Comment: There's a random forests class-level sensitivity analysis in R package https://rdrr.io/cran/rfUtilities/man/rf.class.sensitivity.html